# i would seek assistance on the following batch script on set and goto

Tags: batch-file

is there a way for me to set a batch script after user input , it set a variable and then use go to. for example

```
SET INPUTLocation=""
SET /P INPUTLocation=Please select a number:

echo you enter %INPUTlocation%

IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='1'set router="router1" GOTO testnow`$`
IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='2' set router="router2" GOTO testnow'$
IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='3' set router="router3" GOTO testnow'$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean executing multiple commands? You can do that by putting them in parentheses:

```
SET INPUTLocation=""
SET /P INPUTLocation=Please select a number:

echo you enter %INPUTlocation%

IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='1' (
  set router="router1" 
  GOTO testnow`$`
)
IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='2' (
  set router="router2" 
  GOTO testnow'$
)
IF /I '%INPUTlocation%'=='3' (
  set router="router3" 
  GOTO testnow'$'
)
```

Note, if you want to input a single character, you may also use the `CHOICE` command. It lets you select a single character from a specified set of characters, and it doesn't require you to press enter afterwards. For these kinds of menu-selections, it is more convenient than `SET`.